# Оборот "так же как"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Какой вариант является правильным? Здесь сравнительный оборот или нерасчленение сложного союза?

1. Датчики дыма, так же, как КТЗ, недорогие, достаточно компактные, имеют длительный срок службы, однако, в отличие от них, являются энергозависимыми.

Они так же, как и КТЗ, представляют собой недорогие, компактные и энергонезависимые устройства.

2. Датчики дыма, так же как КТЗ, недорогие, достаточно компактные, имеют длительный срок службы, однако, в отличие от них, являются энергозависимыми.

Они, так же как и КТЗ, представляют собой недорогие, компактные и энергонезависимые устройства.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Корректно:   Датчики дыма, так же как КТЗ, недорогие, достаточно компактные, имеют длительный срок службы, однако, в отличие от них, являются энергозависимыми.

Они, так же как и КТЗ, представляют собой недорогие, компактные и энергонезависимые устройства.

> ТАК ЖЕ(,) КАК (И), союз; наречие + частица + союз

1. Союз. То же, что «равно как (и)». Синтаксические конструкции с союзом «так же как (и)» выделяются знаками препинания (запятыми). Между частями союза знаки препинания не требуются.

**Так же как в средневековой харчевне, нас встречали дома бревенчатые темные стены, законопаченные желтым мхом, пылающие поленья в печке и запах тмина. К. Паустовский, Бакенщик. Я знала, так же как и она, что рано или поздно наступит день, когда мы поневоле заговорим и простим друг другу долгое молчание. Ч. Айтматов, Материнское поле.**

> 2. Наречие + частица + союз. Запятая ставится перед словом «как».

**От тяжелой росистой травы кругом и от цветов, ночных цветов, только теперь раскрывших свои головки, пахло так же, как от волос Анны. С. Сергеев-Ценский, Печаль полей. Совершенно так же, как в жмурках, бывало мы, ребята, шли с завязанными глазами, так и она переступала с лапки на лапку в направлении леса. М. Пришвин, Охотничьи собаки.**

> **См.: Справочник по пунктуации. Свинцов Виктор Викторович, Пахомов Владимир Маркович, Филатова Ирина Витальевна**

Answer (score 3):

Если союз "как" и указательные слова "так", "такой" с частицей "же" оказываются рядом, то они могут сливаться в единое союзное сочетание: Он, так же как Ильюшин, учился в Военно-воздушной академии (А. Яковлев). (Лопатин В. В.)

Датчики дыма, так же как КТЗ, недорогие, достаточно компактные, имеют длительный срок службы, однако, в отличие от них, являются энергозависимыми.
Они, так же как и КТЗ, представляют собой недорогие, компактные и энергонезависимые устройства.

Answer (score 1):

Да, союзы сливаются, запятая ставится один раз, но она может быть также только перед "как":

> *Датчики дыма так же, как КТЗ, недорогие, достаточно компактные, имеют длительный срок службы, однако в отличие от них являются энергозависимыми. Они так же, как и КТЗ, представляют собой недорогие, компактные и энергонезависимые устройства.*

По-моему, это такой же случай, как с "потому что", где запятая может ставиться вначале, а может между этими словами, в зависимости от интонационного выделения.

*В отличие от них* лучше не обособлять, на мой взгляд, а то получается нагромождение запятых.